# How to resolve this conflict with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please help me resolve this conflict with my javascript validation?

The form does not submit. But if I remove `onsubmit="return btnSubmitPD_OnClick()` it redirect the form correctly. But of course I need that function.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Testing</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#Submit').click(function() {
    var emailVal = $('#email').val();
    $.post('checkemail.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {
        if(data=='exist') {
            alert('in'); return false;
        }else{
            $('#form1').submit();
        }

    });
});});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function appIsEmail(str){
    var at="@";
    var dot=".";
    var lat=str.indexOf(at);
    var lstr=str.length;
    var ldot=str.indexOf(dot);
    if (str.indexOf(at)==-1) return false; 

    if (str.indexOf(at)==-1 || str.indexOf(at)==0 || str.indexOf(at)==lstr) return false;
    if (str.indexOf(dot)==-1 || str.indexOf(dot)==0 || str.indexOf(dot)==lstr) return false;
    if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1))!=-1) return false;
    if (str.substring(lat-1,lat)==dot || str.substring(lat+1,lat+2)==dot) return false;
    if (str.indexOf(dot,(lat+2))==-1) return false;
    if (str.indexOf(" ")!=-1) return false;

     return true;
}

function btnSubmitPD_OnClick(){
    frmReg = document.getElementById("form1");

    if (!appIsEmail(frmReg.email.value)){
        alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
        frmReg.email.focus();
        return false;        
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="view.php" onsubmit="return btnSubmitPD_OnClick()">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ArunJain why did you suggest `.noConflict`?

Answer (score 0):

Several Things:

It is better to bind a submit event to your form, rather than a click event on your submit button, this is to cater for cases where users press enter on the email text field:

```
$('#form1').submit(function() { // change from $('#Submit').click
```

Then inside the new `submit` handler, you call call the email validation method:

```
var emailVal = $('#email').val();
if(btnSubmitPD_OnClick() === false) return false;
```

Then, to avoid infinite `submit` loop, you need to change:

```
else{
            $('#form1').submit();
        }
```

to

```
else{
            $('#form1')[0].submit(); // native submit on form element
        }
```

Or as mplungjan noted in his comment, simply change your

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

To use `type="submit"`

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

And add

```
if(btnSubmitPD_OnClick() === false) return false;
```

Before your call to `$.post`

Comment: or change the button to a submit button and return true/false

Comment: YW - you can even do `return btnSubmitPD_OnClick();`